# Too Long recursion to generate game tree of Tic Tac Toe

Tags: python, recursion, tic-tac-toe

I am trying to generate complete  game tree of Tic Tac Toe. I assumed 1 for player 1 and -1 for player 2. I used the follwoing code:

```
nodeDict = {}
nodescore = {}
succDict = {}
def buildTree(S, p, node):
    succ = []
    succScore = []  

    if move_was_winning_move(S, p):
        print "It is a winning move for\n",S,p,node
        return
    elif move_was_winning_move(S, p*-1):
        print "It is a winning move for\n",S,p*-1,node
        return
    elif not move_still_possible(S):
        return

    # if S is not terminal: switch player & compute successors
    if not move_was_winning_move(S, p):
        rs, cs = np.where(S==0)

    for j in range(rs.size):
        Ssucc = np.copy(S)
        Ssucc[rs[j],cs[j]] = p
        newnode = max(nodeDict.keys())+1
        nodeDict[newnode] = Ssucc
        succ.append(newnode)
    succDict[node] = succ

   nextPlayer = p * (-1)

   for s in succ:
        buildTree(nodeDict[s], nextPlayer, s)

   return
```

When I start the code from a state:

```
0  0  0
0  0  0
0  0  0
```

It runs too long. What i found that, there should be maximum 9! number of nodes, it should not be too long to run.

Can anybody tell me if I am wrong on the code? Or is there any way to optimise the recursion?

Comment: Out of curiosity, is the code that begins with `nextPlayer = p...` indented correctly in your local file?

Comment: What is "too long"? as it's 9! and the computations in each iteration aren't trivial (can take a ms or longer) it can easily run for multiple minutes.

Comment: It runs like hour. I feel that, it is some how at a infinite situation.

Answer (score 1):

A few comments:

After you check to see if you are at the end of a branch in your tree, you don't need to recheck to see if S is terminal:

```
# if S is not terminal: switch player & compute successors
    ##if not move_was_winning_move(S, p):   THIS LINE IS NOT NECESSARY
    rs, cs = np.where(S==0)
```

Also, it seems to me that as your `move_was_winning_move` and `move_still_possible` functions are called at least once per iteration, they could significantly contribute to the run time, but you haven't shown us that code, so we can't help you optimize it.

What you really need to do is look into the [`cProfile` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html) and figure out what the bottleneck in your code is.

Answer (score 0):

You could always multithread the program, although this approach might be overkill.  Multithreading is a way of using multiple cores to run the program instead of just one, which is the default way python programs run.  This does speed up the runtime of the program, though I can't say by how much.  Python docs explain how to multithread much better than I can, so I'd look there first for instructions on how to multithread.